# Report of Out of Stock Products

Tags: reports

How do I get a report of all products that are Out of Stock on Magento 1.7.0.2?  Currently our Quickbooks and Magento do not communicate so I rely on our sales team to inform me when products are out of stock.  Downfall is they fail to communicate when products are back in stock.  It would be great if I can generate a report from Magento weekly showing the products that are currently marked Out of Stock on our Magento website.